# Make call from modelview kotlin class to method which returns Observable

Tags: database, kotlin, view, model, observable

I have method which makes the database select and return Observable<>.
How can I call such a method from Kotlin modelview calss?

```
private val _response = MutableStateFlow(Response())
val response: StateFlow<Response> = _response

suspend fun getResponse() {
        viewModelScope.launch(exceptionHandler) {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
              _response.emit(apiCall)//Type mismatch. need Response but getting Observable<Response!>!
            }
        }
}
```

another class

```
public Observable<Responnse> apiCall(){
    return cacheObservable.flatMap(response -> {return observableResponse});
};
```

Comment: then I make emit in viewModelScope.launch on function which return Observable, I m getting error Type mismatch. need object but getting Observable<Object!>!

Comment: added code to question

Comment: What type is `_response` in the above code? What does your `apiCall()` function have to do with this? It doesn't really make sense to have a suspend function that launches a coroutine in another scope and doesn't do anything else, since it's not suspending.

Comment: added some line to code. apiCall() it is old java code wich makes call to server, getResponse() with _response it's new code in AndroidViewModel class witch will be injected with  _response value to composable UI.

Comment: Did you mean to put `_response.emit(apiCall())` instead of `_response.emit(apiCall)`? Is Observable from RxJava?

Comment: Yes, apiCall(), and yes Observable from RxJava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are conversions between Rx and Kotlin coroutines in the `kotlinx` reactive library. Add to your dependencies:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-rx2:1.6.4"
// Match the coroutines version you are already using. 
// Change rx2 to rx3 depending on which version of Rx you're using.
```

Then you can call `asFlow()` on an Observable to convert it to a Flow, so your ViewModel code would become the following:

```
val response: StateFlow<Response> = apiCall().asFlow()
    .flowOn(exceptionHandler)
    .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000L), Response())
```

No need for specifying a dispatcher or creating a separate `getResponse()` function to initiate the call. It will begin the call the first time you collect this flow.

I used `WhileSubscribed(5000L)` as an example. This allows resources to be conserved while a Fragment goes off screen, but avoids having to restart it if it's brief like during a screen rotation.